# Call database oracle connection from a method to another in Java

Tags: java, database, oracle, selenium

I need to call some strings like (username) from the below method. the package name is login and the database method is SQLConnector and the testcase is Firstlogin. I need to call the connection of database in Firstlogin to use strings from it in Firstlogin and to execute queries in Firstlogin too:

```
package login;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SQLConnector {
static Connection con = null;
private static Statement stmt;
public static String DB_URL =  "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.96.0.65:1521:orcl";   
public static String DB_USER = "POS_SOF";
public static String DB_PASSWORD = "POS_SOF";
    static String username;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
       try{
              String dbClass = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
              Class.forName(dbClass).newInstance();
              Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
              stmt = con.createStatement();
              }
              catch (Exception e)
              {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }

}
@Test
public void test() {
       try{
       String query = "select * from users where id = '45450'";

       String expectedEmpName = "test1234";
       ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (res.next())
       {
        username = res.getString("user_name");
        System.out.print(username);
        assertEquals(expectedEmpName, username);

       }

       }

       catch(Exception e)

       {

              e.printStackTrace();

       }     

}
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
       if (con != null) {
       con.close();

       }

}
```

}
 in the second method which I need to use the database connection in:

```
package login;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import login.SQLConnector;


public class FirstLogin {

private String baseUrl;
private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://DownLoads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://100.96.0.650:9443";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testAddAccount() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/POSAdminTool/AdminTool/SearchPOS.faces");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("form1:usernameLabel")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("form1:usernameLabel")).sendKeys(SQLConnector.username);
    driver.findElement(By.id("form1:passwordLabel")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("form1:passwordLabel")).sendKeys("1234");
    driver.findElement(By.id("form1:btn_login")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html body table.mainTable tbody tr td p.menuItem a"));
    action.moveToElement(element);
    action.click();
    action.perform();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add Account")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:locationID")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:locationID")).sendKeys("9999");
    driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:menu1")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:menu1")).sendKeys("10000");
    driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:menuStatus1")).click();
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:usageList"))).selectByVisibleText("Pharmacy");
    driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:textareaDescription1")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:textareaDescription1")).sendKeys("New");
    driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:addAcctTerminal")).click();
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("AddAcctTerminalData:statusList"))).selectByVisibleText("Active");
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("AddAcctTerminalData:TermList"))).selectByVisibleText("Point of Sale");
    driver.findElement(By.id("AddAcctTerminalData:textSN1")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("AddAcctTerminalData:textSN1")).sendKeys("22-55-88");
    driver.findElement(By.id("AddAcctTerminalData:textPin1")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("AddAcctTerminalData:textPin1")).sendKeys("1234");
    driver.findElement(By.id("AddAcctTerminalData:add")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:textDailyLimit1")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:textDailyLimit1")).sendKeys("10000");
    driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:textCreditLimit1")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:textCreditLimit1")).sendKeys("10000");
    driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:button1")).click();
    assertEquals("Account Added Successfully", driver.findElement(By.id("AddAccountSuccess:CorrectMessage")).getText());
    String AddedAccount = "SELECT CODE FROM ACCOUNTS WEHER ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ACCOUNTS)";
    String AccountCode = driver.findElement(By.id("AddAccountSuccess:AccountCode")).getText();
    System.out.print(AccountCode);
    System.out.print(AddedAccount);
    assertEquals(AddedAccount, AccountCode);

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
        fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes:

- Make `Connection` object non static
- Remove the declaration of local variable `con` in `@Before` method, i.e. change

  `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);`

  to

  `con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);`

Declaring a local variable in method (with the same name as instance variable) shadows the instance variable and hence, the instance variable never gets initialised. With the above change, `con` will get initialised before any test runs and you will be able to use it in any method.

Comment: Here is what I did:
  public Connection con = null;
con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

import oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement;

    public class SQLConnector {
    static final String DB_URL =  "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.96.0.65:1521:orcl";   
    static final String DB_USER = "POS_SOF";
    static final String DB_PASSWORD = "POS_SOF";
        static String username;

    @Before
    public Connection setUp() throws Exception {
    Connection connection = null;

           try {
                try {

                    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }

                System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

                  System.out.println("Status: \n - Connecting to database...");
                  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
                  System.out.println(" - You are connected to the " + DB_URL);
                  }
                  catch (Exception e)
                  {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  }
        return connection;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Connection conn = setUp();
           try {
                /*Oracle thin connection require OraclePreparedStatement class*/
                String query = "select * from users where id = '45450'";
                OraclePreparedStatement stmt = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(query); // is not necessary needed to pass query variable

                String expectedEmpName = "test1234";
                ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while (res.next()) {
                    username = res.getString("user_name");
                    System.out.print(username);
                    assertEquals(expectedEmpName, username);
               }

           } 
           catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (conn != null)
                        conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    se.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   
    }
```